# Layer getting distorted when being rotated in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

I am simply trying to rotate a rectangle while keeping the quality. Instead this is what I end up with. Anyone have a solution?[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, transform the shape into Smart Object before rotating